# Android: Check if object is present in database using Room and RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-room

I'm using `Room` as ORM and here is my Dao interface:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 1")
    fun get(): Single<User?>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun add(profile: User)
}
```

In other hand I have a method in Repository which should check if the user is login or not, here is the implementation code:

```
override fun isUserLogin(): Single<Boolean> = userDao
            .get().async()
            .onErrorReturn { null }
            .map { it != null }
```

Room will throw the following exception if no row matches the query:

> Query returned empty result set: SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 1

I want to return `null` in this case, but when I execute the code it throw an exception with the following messsage:

> Value supplied was null

I can't use `Optional` because Dao is returning `Single<User?>` so `onErrorReturn` should return the same type.

How can I check if the user exists or not without changing Dao?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the proper way to do this, besides Android and Room, is to use `COUNT` in your query.

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from User")
fun usersCount() : Single<Int>
```

It will return the number of rows in the table, if it's 0 you know there is no user in the db, so.

```
override fun isUserLogin(): Single<Int> = userDao
            .usersCount()
            .async()
            .map { it > 0 }
```

If you really want to do it the ugly way though:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 1")
fun get(): Single<User>
```

Don't use a nullable type, it's pointless. Then map to Boolean and handle the exception:

```
override fun isUserLogin(): Single<Boolean> = userDao
        .get()
        .async()
        .map { true }
        .onErrorReturn { false }
```

Comment: If you use Single<User> in the DAO then room will always throw a EmptyResultSetException when there are no records in the database - it's maybe fine in this case as onErrorReturn catches this, but if you call the DAO in a different place you'll need to handle the error. With Flowable<List<User>> you will at least get a result set back, which will be empty if there are no records.

Comment: If you need to query all the Users then using `List<User>` makes sense, if you just need the row count though, I think that returning the row count directly is the cleanest thing to do. Querying for User models when you just need the count is a pigwork.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Maybe`, which accurately models the response expecting either 0 results, 1 result or an exception.

Comment: it throws: The MaybeSource is empty

Comment: Presumably you're doing `toSingle`, a single cannot be 'empty' by definition so this means an empty `Maybe` turns into an error condition `Single`

Answer (score 0):

If you change your DAO to return a Flowable list of users you can then map this into a boolean value by checking the size of the list.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 1")
fun get(): Flowable<List<User>>
```

e.g.

```
fun isUserLogin(): Single<Boolean> = userDao
    .get()
    .flatMapSingle { Single.just(it.size == 1) }
    .onErrorReturn { false }
    .first(false)
```